# Fortran storage_size intrinsic function

Tags: fortran

I am looking at the storage_size intrinsic function introduced in Fortran 2008 to obtain the size of a user-defined type [man storage size](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/fortran/win/lref_for/source_files/intrinsic_storage_size.htm). It returns the size in bits, not bytes. I am wondering what the rationale is behind returning the size in bits instead of bytes. 
Since I need the size in bytes, I am simply going to divide the result by 8. Is it safe to assume that the size returned will always be divisible by 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not even safe to expect byte is always 8 bits (see `CHARACTER_STORAGE_SIZE` in module `iso_fortran_env`)! For rationale for the `storage_size()` contact someone from SC22/WG5 or X3J3, but one of the former members always says (on comp.lang.fortran) these questions don't have much sense and a single clear answer. There was often just someone pushing this variant and not the other.

My guess would be the symmetry with the former function `bit_size()` is one of the reasons. And why is there `bit_size()` and not `byte_size()`? I would guess you do not have to multiply it with the byte size (and check how large is one byte) and you can apply the bit manipulation procedures instantly.

To your last question. Yes, on a machine with 8-bit bytes (other machines do not have Fortran 2008 compilers AFAIK) the bit size will always be divisible by 8 as one byte is the smallest addressable piece of memory and structures cannot use just part of one byte.

Comment: Thanks. I see that there is also a c_sizeof in the iso_c_binding module, which returns the size in bytes.

Comment: Yes, but that one is limited only to C interoperable structures in Fortran 2008. Most compilers also support `sizeof()` as an extension.